# HTML5 Semantic markup of particular date/time module

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

I have a element on my page that informs the user of the days an event is going on, the month and year and finally how many days are to go before the event. I was wondering if the following within the HTML5 specification is the correct HTML5 markup pattern for this data.

**example of what the markup needs to produce**

[image]

**my markup (slightly different to the image above):**

```
<section>
    <div>London</div>
    <time datetime="2013-02-20">20</time>
    –
    <time datetime="2013-02-21">21</time>
    <time datetime="2013-02">Feburary 2013</time>
    <div>24 days to go</div>
</section>
```

Any suggestions on correct markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether a `<section>`-element is the right wrapper for this container. The [specs on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/sections.html#the-section-element) say:

> A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.

In the example markup, you don't have a heading, which could be added, but I don't think, that the date itself "*is a thematic grouping of content*", it is more a meta information to some other content.

Regarding the `<time>`-elements another way to write this thingy could be:

```
<div>London</div>
<time datetime="P2D">20 - 21</time>
<time datetime="2013-02-20">Feburary 2013</time>
<div>24 days to go</div>
```

The first one describes a *duration* of two days, which the event will last. The second specifies *the day the event starts*. Without the tags it still reads "*London 20 - 21 February 2013 24 days to go*".

You can read more about it here on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org):

[4.6.11 The time element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element)
[2.4.5.9 Durations](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#valid-duration-string)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware of "durations" eithin the datetime attr.

Comment: Just a quick note, in my markup maybe "London" could be the heading therefore justifying the section tag?

Comment: @pixeltooth I was thinking about that too, putting the location as the heading. I think that can be a good solution.

Comment: Personally, from the W3 quote, and from experience, I would sugest section is a good match in this scenario. This is because it is grouping dates into a single section